# How to correctly solve boost dependency issues

Tags: c++, linux, boost, build, dependencies

I am using `cpprestsdk/casablanca` in my project. `cpprestsdk` is dependent on `Boost` library. Several weeks ago I downloaded `cpprest`'s source and built `*.so` library with `Boost 1.65.1` and some version of `OpenSSL`. My system is `Arch Linux`. 
Due to a recent events with Meltdown and Spectre exploits, I've made a full system upgrade (kernel 4.14, latest versions of libraries) and now I have `Boost 1.66.0` and a more recent version of `OpenSSL`.

When I try to compile my project, linker states that

```
libboost_[random, system, etc. - there are many of them].so.1.65.1, needed by /usr/local/lib/libcpprest.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

It also shows warning about SSL because latest version of `cpprestsdk` is incompatible with `OpenSSL 1.1+` so you have to build it (`cpprest`) with the previous.

```
 libcrypto.so.1.0.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libcpprest.so, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1.
```

Obviously, there is no `boost 1.65.1` installation on my system, so there is no point in using -rpath.

I figured that I should build another version of boost, but several sources claim that it is bad idea to store multiple versions of boost on one system. I am not sure how to correctly store custom boost version either.
I can rebuild `libccprest` with the current library but it'll only work till the next update.
I guess that in order to completely build my project, I should embed specific versions of `Boost`, `SSL` and other dependencies into my project.

What are general solutions for such a problem? How do you manage and deploy custom (non-system-side) versions of shared libraries? Every "big" library has it's own installation system/scripts so I have no idea how to integrate it to my own project's build system. I've never encounter issues with libraries before so I am not sure what path to choose. I am using `Makefile` to build my project.